# mysql - group by to get oldest and newest dates into one row

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I have tbl_events

```
key  userID    date

1     1         1.1.2000
2     1         1.1.2017
3     2         2.2.1990
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
select distinct userID, date [that is earliest eg row 1] as earliest_date, 
date [that is latest eg row 2] as latest_date
from tbl_events
```

if a userid has only one row in tbl_events then tbl_events.date would serve as both the earliest and latest_date

ie my result would be:

```
userID    earliest_date    latest_date

1         1.1.2000         1.1.2017
2         2.2.1990         2.2.1990
```

I can do this rather inefficiently with lots of looping but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with "group by" or i have seen queries that seem to contain additional select statements in brackets

If anyone can please point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Thank you.

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` and `MIN()` aggregate function probably saying

```
select userid, max(`date`) as earliest_date,
min(`date`) as furthest_date
from tbl
group by userid;
```